# Rendering partial that belongs to another controller

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, controller, partials, lifx

I've got a menu controller, which is set as my root controller in routes.rb. In my menu view, i try and render the _lights.slim partial with `= render :partial => 'lights/lights'` but i get the following error: `` undefined method `lights' for nil:NilClass ``

**MenuController:**

```
class MenuController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end
end
```

**Menu View** (index.slim)

```
ul.tabs.vertical data-tab=""
  li.tab-title.active
    a href="#panel1a"  Tab 1

.tabs-content.vertical
  #panel1a.content.active
    = render :partial => 'lights/lights'
```

**LightsController**

```
class LightsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :discover_lights
    include LIFX
    @client = LIFX::Client.lan
    @client.discover!
    3.times do
      @client.lights.refresh
      sleep (0.5)
      puts "Found #{@client.lights.count} with labels #{@client.lights}"
    end

    def index
    end
    def new
    end

    def light_toggle
      light = @client.lights.with_label(params[:label])
      light.on? ? light.turn_off : light.turn_on
      redirect_to '/'
    end

  private
    def discover_lights
      @client = LIFX::Client.lan
      @client.discover!
    end
end
```

**Lights View** (_lights.slim)

```
h1.subheader LIFX Lights
table.light-table
  thead
    tr
      th Light
      th Status
      th Power On/Off
      th Brightness
  tbody
  -@client.lights.map do |c|
    tr
      th #{c.label}
      th #{c.power}
      th =link_to 'Toggle', light_path(:label => c.label)
      th #{c.color.brightness.round(2) * 100}%
end
```

**Routes.rb**

```
root 'menu#index'
get '/lights', to: 'lights#index'
get '/lights/:label', to: 'lights#light_toggle', as: 'light'
```

I know this is a no brainer, but i'm stuck as to what to do here. I'm thinking it must be an issue with the way that when `Menu#Index` is called, I never knows about my `LightsController`, and so @client.blablabla will never make sense. But how will I make my app know about my `LightsController` when the view is loaded as a partial

Comment: The problem is `@client` is `nil` in this line `-@client.lights.map do |c|`.Nothing wrong with rendering the `partial`.

Comment: Yeah, I know the problem is there, but in what way would I make my MenuController aware of the logic in my LightsController

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Partials**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#overview-how-the-pieces-fit-together)

You must appreciate that Partials are *not* controller-dependent (being stored in a controllers' view directory does not tie them for use with that controller)

This means if you have the functionality to support the partial in another controller, you *should* be able to use it in different parts of your app

--

**Error**

This leads us to the identification of the problem you're receiving.

It's not the *calling* of the partial which causes an issue - it's how you're referring to the code inside it:

> undefined method `lights' for nil:NilClass

The error is clearly that you're trying to call the `lights` method on an object / variable which doesn't exist. This is defined inside the `partial` itself here:

```
@client.lights.map do |c|
```

Therefore, you need to be able to pass the correct data  to the partial, enabling it to load the `@client` object without being dependent on the controller

--

**Fix**

To do this, you may wish to consider using [partial locals](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#passing-local-variables) -

```
<%= render partial: "lights/lights", locals: {client: @client} %>
```

This means that every time you call the partial, you'll have to pass the `@client` object into the `client` local var, thus allowing the partial to run controller-independently.

Here's how you'd handle it in the partial itself:

```
#app/views/lights/_lights.slim
- client.lights.map do |c|
```

Comment: Thanks you for a very elaborate answer on a seemingly simple question! :) Appreciated!